# HDMI1 Disconnected Plasma TV xrandr Ubuntu 14.04lts

Tags: video, hdmi, xrandr, gpu-driver, tv

My Machine: **HP Pavilion g6**

- Processor: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
- Memory: 3937MB (1217MB used)
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Resolution: 1366x768 pixels
- Audio Adapter: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
- SCSI Disks-
- ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0
- hp CDDVDW SN-208BB

  $ xrandr
  Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
  LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
     1366x768       60.0*+   39.9
     1360x768       59.8     60.0
     1024x768       60.0
     800x600        60.3     56.2
     640x480        59.9
  VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

  $ lshw -C display

  *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz 
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:45 memory:c2000000-c23fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)

I'm trying to connect this machine to a **Panasonic Plasma TV TH-42PA60A**
50/60Hz, 294w via HDMI1.

I have a HDMI cable direct to the television (thus from the TV to the laptop). When I plug the HDMI cable in (with the laptop off, then powering up, or plugging in when signed in, then rebooting) there is no signal detected by the laptop or the television, which is set to HDMI.

In system setttings > displays, no additional display has been recognized. None is recognized if I "detect display".

Yes, the cable and the television work. Yesterday we brought in another more modern monitor, connected two XBOX 360's via Cat5 had a 7-player epic night of HALO on two TV's and one of the two XBOX 360's was plugged into the Plasma Panasonic TV direct via the HDMI cable. No issues.

Is there a way to get the HDMI1 to recognize the Plasma TV on my machine? That is my question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could try the latest intel driver at [ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

Comment: and also try to power down the TV by pulling plug from AC power like 2 minutes before trying again

Comment: Allrighty...sorry it took so long to get back. I tried both of your suggestions, and thank you for those. Neither worked. Latest drivers installed and updated, TV unplugged and replugged, xrandr still shows that HDMI1 is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it temporary by connecting the screen during startup and with some luck it works.